# Export content of a row into a text file with a certain structure

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet linked to a Google form. I would like to export the content of each row into a new text file each time a new answer (row) is given like in the example (see picture attached). The additional complexity is that I would like the file to be structured like in the example using the text in the first row, specifying the value and adding a carriage return.

[image: Click to see picture]

I am using as a starting point the attached script but I didn't manage to adapt it to my problem and make it work. Also, every time I launch this script, it runs for a very long time and creates a huge number of untitled files.
I hope you can help.

```
function export() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i in sheets) {
    var name = sheets[i].getSheetName();
    var fo = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
    var folder = fo.hasNext() ? fo.next() : 
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(name);
    var values = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift();
    var filename, text;
    for (var j in values) {
      [filename, text] = values[j];
      folder.getFilesByName(filename).hasNext() || 
      folder.createFile(filename, text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not provide a valid file name that's why unnamed files.

Use below code to install a **onFormSubmit** trigger to spreadsheet where the form responses are written. It'll then create a file everytime the form is submitted and save it in a folder named after the response sheet. Run the `setup` function once, and comment it out. Test by submitting the form.

```
function setup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

// run this function one to setup formSubmit trigger
// then comment it out, like this
setup();

function myFunction(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var name = sheet.getName();

  var text = 'This file contains all the details of your purchase:\n';

  for (var key in e.namedValues) {
    text += key + ': ' + e.namedValues[key][0] + '\n';
  }

  var fo = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
  var folder = fo.hasNext() ? fo.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(name);

  folder.createFile(Date.now() + '', text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```